# as3: secure xml-files - best method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I want to **secure any queries to my /xmlrpc.php** to ban bots and others from reading out my database.

What's the best method to authenticate the user and that his query has been sent from my main-swf ?

- by using oAuth services
- by using secureTokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to do it, or are you asking which of the 2 is the best method? In fairness, they're both essentially the same thing, and just differ in terms of implementation

Comment: thanks - do you know any alternative mthods maybe and which is the most secure one?

Comment: facebook uses oauth, so that's good for me :D. in their docs, they talk about a method to verify that calls were coming from the fb server: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/. you could probably reverse-engineer something similar to that

Comment: another solution is to site-lock your project (assuming that you're only running it in one place). There are a number of code examples on the web, but you'll need to encrypt your swf to make it secure (to stop people just commenting out the sitelock). From what a number of people have said, secureSWF (http://www.kindisoft.com/) is the only one worth using - i use it in my games - and the professional edition comes with a domain lock (plus local execution disabling). even, if you get the basic, it should encrypt your own site-locking code fine